# add object to type object with list ref

Tags: java, casting, dynamic-programming

Im having the following method and the method return object type ,my question 
is if the method cardianlity = true we create item object type list but return it
like type object so if I want to use the method return parameter how should I do 
that for add item(object) to it ?

*This is the method*

```
private static Object createRefObj(boolean cardinality) {

    List<Object> itemObject = null;
    Object specObject = null;
    if (cardinality == true) {
        itemObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
        return itemObject;
    } else {
        return specObject;
    }

}
```

*here im calling to the method*

```
Object refObject = createRefObj(cardinality);
```

how should i add object to the refObject in case its array list

Comment: You can use instanceof to check the type of object returned and accordingly assign and use it.

Comment: Are you aware that for false input your always receive null as the result ? what exactly are you trying to achieve here ? can you clarify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use:

```
if (cardinality == true)
```

And you can check:

```
if (refObject instanceof List){
    List myList = (List) refObject;
}
```

But I think it better to create two functions, one returns an `Object` and one returns a `List`. Use `cardinality` to decide what function to call.